# Can Google Photos on iOS use mobile data connection to back up?

Tags: google-photos

For some reason, I already turned on Mobile Data for Google Photos in iPhone settings, but it still says "Waiting for Wifi" in the app.

After I turned on Wifi, and tapped on the backup button, and went to another app, the backup didn't run in the background for the first time. The second time, it did run in the background. Is there a way to make it always back up in the background?

Comment: It's in the backup settings of the app itself to allow backup on data. I don't have the app rn, could you add the screenshot once you find it in your(future) answer? Also, turn off low power mode for BG backup.

Comment: @ankii it might be worth trying... because the majority of phone data might be photos and videos, and true, I can download that 32 or 45GB to a computer, but then, back it up to a hard drive? (in 10, 15 years, I really don't know where those hard drives are). But if I back up to Google Photos, it'd **unlimited** storage and in "good" quality, and so 10, 20 years later, I know exactly where the photos are

Answer (score 1):

> Back up on mobile data: If you don’t want to wait for Wi-Fi to back up your photos, under “When to back up”, tap Use cellular data to back up photos or Use cellular data to back up videos. Charges from your service provider may apply if you upload using your mobile network.

<sup>from https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?hl=en&ref_topic=6156061&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1</sup>

Also, turn off low power mode for background backup

As OP puts it nicely:

> ...the key is: you have to allow iOS to allow mobile data, and allow the Google Photos apps to use mobile data, so there are 2 settings to be touched. [..] we can have on/on, off/off, on/off, and off/on, and only on/on allows using mobile data...

<sup>From: [Can Google Photos on iOS use mobile data connection to back up?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371682/can-google-photos-on-ios-use-mobile-data-connection-to-back-up/371686?noredirect=1#comment498609_371686)</sup>

Comment: ah ok, I think the key is: you have to allow iOS to allow mobile data, and allow the Google Photos apps to use mobile data, so there are 2 settings to be touched.  So it is a bit weird: we can have on/on, off/off, on/off, and off/on, and only on/on allows using mobile data... maybe it can be merged, but Google Photos settings let you choose back up by mobile data for photos and/or for videos... not sure if iOS settings can allow this choice